# data not inerted correctly when going through a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 $answersql = "INSERT INTO Penalty_Marks (PenaltyAnswer, PenaltyMarks, QuestionId) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

   $c = count($_POST['incorrect']);

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
    {


$incorrect = $_POST['incorrect'][$i];
$answerMarks = $_POST['answerMarks'][$i];
$numQuestion = $_POST['numQuestion'][$i];

$insertanswer->bind_param('sii', $incorrect, $answerMarks, $numQuestion);
$insertanswer->execute();

}
```

The above insert is not inserting all the incorrect answers into the table, it is only inserting one incorrect answer per question. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the currect db table looks like:

```
PenaltyAnswerId PenaltyAnswer  PenaltyMarks  QuestionId
1               A              4             12
2               D              1             13
```

Below is what it should of been like:

```
PenaltyAnswerId PenaltyAnswer  PenaltyMarks  QuestionId
1               A              4             12
2               B              3             12
3               D              0             12
4               D              1             13
5               E              1             13
```

Below is form:

```
<form id="PenaltyMarks" action="insertpenaltymarks.php" method="post">

    <table id='penaltytbl'>
    <?php

    foreach($ques_ans as $questionId => $inc_ans)
    {
        $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
        $row_count = 0;
        $inc_ans = array_values($inc_ans);

    ?>

    <tr class="questiontd">
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="numQuestion[]" value="<?php echo$questionId?>" />
    </td>

    <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php echo$inc_ans[$row_count];?>">
    </td>

    <td>
    <input  name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" value='0'  />
    </td>

    </tr>
        <?php
            //remaining incorrect answers in separate row (if any) follows here
        if($row_count < $q_row_span - 1) 
        {
            for($i=($row_count + 1); $i<$q_row_span; $i++) { ?>     
                <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="hidden" class="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php echo$inc_ans[$i];?>">
                </td>

                <td class="answermarkstd">
                <input  name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" value='0'  />            
                </td>
                </tr>
        <?php
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
    </table>
<input id="submitBtn" name="submitPenalty" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" />
    </form>
```

Below is jquery handling submit:

```
myClickHandler = function(e) {

       if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n")) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "insertpenaltymarks.php",
           data: $("#PenaltyMarks").serialize(),
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
         return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };

    $('#PenaltyMarks').submit(myClickHandler);

});
```

UPDATE:

```
Question Table:

QuestionId (PK auto)  (int 10)
QuestionNo  (int 4)
QuestionContent (varchar 5000)


Penalty_Marks Table;

PenaltyAnswerId (PK auto) (int 10)
PenaltyAnswer (Varchar 5)
PenaltyMarks (int 3)
QuestionId (FK)  (int 10) Reference to QuestionId in Question Table
```

Comment: Can you paste the structure of your tables (primary keys, index...)

Comment: @m4t1t0 included structure in update

Comment: how to you sumbit the form? I can see not submit button. Do you submit it with javascript?

Comment: @hek2mgl I did not include it in form above. The submit button is in form then use jquery/ajax to navigate to php/mysqli page. Updated form code and included jquery

Comment: @user1964964 are you sure the values are submitted properly? can you add a `var_dump($_POST);` to your question?

Comment: Let me test answer below, if doesn't work I will update question, give me 15 -20 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

With your current code, you can `var_dump` and found that the `$_POST['numQuestion']` array may contains a fewer member than the `$_POST['incorrect'][$i]` array. I have updated my code too.

```php
<form id="PenaltyMarks" action="insertpenaltymarks.php" method="post">

<table id='penaltytbl'>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionId => $inc_ans)
{
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    $row_count = 0;
    $inc_ans = array_values($inc_ans);
?>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="numQuestion[<?php echo $questionId; ?>]" value="<?php echo$questionId?>" />
</td>

<td>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[<?php echo $questionId; ?>][]" value="<?php echo$inc_ans[$row_count];?>">
</td>

<td>
<input  name="answerMarks[<?php echo $questionId; ?>][]" type="text" data-type="qmark" value='0'  />
</td>

</tr>
    <?php
        //remaining incorrect answers in separate row (if any) follows here
    if($row_count < $q_row_span - 1) 
    {
        for($i=($row_count + 1); $i<$q_row_span; $i++) { ?>     
            <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[<?php echo $questionId; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $inc_ans[$i];?>">
            </td>

            <td class="answermarkstd">
            <input  name="answerMarks[<?php echo $questionId; ?>][]" type="text" data-type="qmark" value='0' />            
            </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
}

?>
</table>
<input id="submitBtn" name="submitPenalty" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" />
</form>
```

The insertion script should be changed too :)

```php
foreach($_POST['incorrect'] as $questionId => $incorrectArray)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($incorrectArray), $i++)
    {
        $incorrect = $_POST['incorrect'][$questionId][$i];
        $answerMarks = $_POST['answerMarks'][$questionId][$i];
        $numQuestion = $_POST['numQuestion'][$questionId];

        $insertanswer->bind_param('sii', $incorrect, $answerMarks, $numQuestion);
        $insertanswer->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if the opener do so?

Comment: Can i ask how this can be coded for one of the names? I will then include it for the other names

Comment: Your input form contains multiple questions (with their answers) or just one question and its answer?

Comment: Input form contains multiple questions with their answers. Each question has either single or multiple answers

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, tested and found that my previous conclusion is not true :) I have update the source code. The new solution will group wrong answers of each question into an array. Thank you for helping me finding a mistake.

Comment: @TrungHieuLe It is now not inserting anything into the db. Do I need to change something in php/mysqli script? Just to make sure, in the `numQuestion` name you do not have `[]` at the end, Im assuming you know about this?

Comment: Oop, I forgot to update the insertion script :) We should change it a bit. I have updated my asnwer. In the `numQuestion` name you do not have [] at the end because we need a one-dimension array to store `questionId` while we need a two-dimension array to store incorrect answer and their marks, grouped by `questionId`.

Comment: Everything looks perfect. Thank you very much for your help :)